# Integration with limits

Tags: matlab

any body help me writing a proper code for integration of "Ufluid equation"

```
U=3.888889
H=0.25
r = variable
Ufluid= 1.5*U*(1.0 - (2.0*r/H).^2)
```

I want to integrate "Ufluid equation"
where 'r' varies from [-0.125,0.125] and whole range of 'r' is divided in 20 parts.

How i write that in matlab code formation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are asking for can be obtained in many ways.

Using symbolic integration.

```
syms r
Ufluid = 1.5*U*(1.0 - (2.0*r/H).^2);
int(Ufluid, -0.125, 0.125)
% = 0.9722
```

With Simpson integration method.

```
fun = @(r) 1.5*U*(1.0 - (2.0*r/H).^2);
quad(fun, -0.125, 0.125)
% = 0.9722
```

Or with the `trapz` function.

```
range = linspace(-0.125, 0.125, 21);
y = 1.5*U*(1.0 - (2.0*range/H).^2);
trapz(range, y)
% = 0.9698
```

Comment: Using symbolic integration method is not work every time i get the error 

"Undefined function 'syms' for input arguments of type 'char'"

other parts are very helpful.
thanks

Comment: Maybe you don't have the license for the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
U=3.888889
H=0.25
r = linspace(-0.125, 0.125, 21);
Ufluid= 1.5*U*(1.0 - (2.0*r/H).^2);
sum(Ufluid)*(r(2)-r(1))
% = 0.9698
```

Since an integral is a continuous sum, you can evaluate the function at several points, sum the results, and multiply by the step size to perform a piece-wise integration

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include an explanation of what it does and why it is the best solution to the problem. This will not only help the OP, but also future visitors as well.